# C# Linq that includes sorting and grouping

Tags: c#, linq

This is my code:

```
public class Photos
{
    public long PhotoLabel { get; set; }        
    public int UserID { get; set; }
}

List<Photos> photolist = new List<Photos>();
var result1 = photolist.OrderByDescending(p => p.PhotoLabel).ThenBy(r => r.UserID).ToList();
```

If I display the contents now, this is what I get (First sorted in descending order of `PhotoLabel` and then sorted by `UserID`:

```
|------|---------------------|---------------------|
| Row  |     UserID          |    PhotoLabel       |
|----------------------------|---------------------|
| 1    |      92             |  20180729181046     |
|----------------------------|---------------------|
| 2    |      92             |  20180729181041     |
|----------------------------|---------------------|
| 3    |      92             |  20180729181037     |
|----------------------------|---------------------|
| 4    |      88             |  20180729174415     |
|----------------------------|---------------------|
| 5    |      88             |  20180729174405     |
|----------------------------|---------------------|
| 6    |      04             |  20180729174358     |
|----------------------------|---------------------|
| 7    |      1              |  20170924183847     |
|----------------------------|---------------------|
| 8    |      1              |  20170921231422     |
|----------------------------|---------------------|
| 9    |      1              |  20170920194624     |
|----------------------------|---------------------|
| 10   |      32             |  20170820114728     |
|----------------------------|---------------------|
| 11   |      32             |  20170820114725     |
|----------------------------|---------------------|
| 12   |      32             |  20170820114421     |
|----------------------------|---------------------|
| 13   |      32             |  20170820114416     |
|----------------------------|---------------------|
| 14   |      1              |  20170225151023     |
|----------------------------|---------------------|
| 15   |      1              |  20170225151000     |
|----------------------------|---------------------|
| 16   |      1              |  20170225150957     |
|----------------------------|---------------------|
```

From the sorted table above, this is what I want to achieve:

- Display groups of `UserIDs` and `PhotoLabels` where `UserIDs` appear 3 or more times in one group (eg: rows 4 and 5 where `UserID=88` and row 6 where `UserID=04` should be eliminated since the `UserID=88` appears just twice in the group and `UserID=04` appears only once in the group).
- Display only the top most group of `UserIDs` and exclude any repeating `UserIDs` (eg: rows 7,8 and 9 displays the `UserID=1` group. Don't display any other `UserID=1` group such as rows 14,15 and 16. )

The expected result from query should be:

```
|------|---------------------|---------------------|
| Row  |     UserID          |    PhotoLabel       |
|----------------------------|---------------------|
| 1    |      92             |  20180729181046     |
|----------------------------|---------------------|
| 2    |      92             |  20180729181041     |
|----------------------------|---------------------|
| 3    |      92             |  20180729181037     |
|----------------------------|---------------------|
| 7    |      1              |  20170924183847     |
|----------------------------|---------------------|
| 8    |      1              |  20170921231422     |
|----------------------------|---------------------|
| 9    |      1              |  20170920194624     |
|----------------------------|---------------------|
| 10   |      32             |  20170820114728     |
|----------------------------|---------------------|
| 11   |      32             |  20170820114725     |
|----------------------------|---------------------|
| 12   |      32             |  20170820114421     |
|----------------------------|---------------------|
| 13   |      32             |  20170820114416     |
|----------------------------|---------------------|
```

Thank you so much in in advance!  :-)

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where are you having trouble?

Comment: does it require to achieve in 1 LINQ? or it is a function output in .NET

Comment: @SKLTFZ it doesn't have to be 1 Linq. Anything that does the job efficiently would do. The table has tons of rows so efficiency is important.

Comment: i think the requirement looks like unable to achieve in LINQ, but it can be implemented easily by a function with a pivot and a list container for the return list

Comment: about efficiency, LINQ is usually not faster than raw iterator. It is just elegant and higher level programming tools for coding

Comment: There's an important part missing from your description. What is your criteria for removing the last three lines? What if there had been three more lines after the last three in the original data set?

Comment: @DrunkenCodeMonkey, if you re-read my requirement, then you would get it. Sorry, not trying to be rude. Since UserID=1 has already appeared in rows 7,8,9 I don't want another repeating group of UserID=1, that's why rows 14,15,16 need to be eliminated. The table has thousands of rows and the logic should be applied to whole table. The data I have given is just a couple of rows from the original table.

Comment: So you only want the first range of contiguous `UserId`?

Comment: This is what was missing. When just looking at the data, there aren't multiple groups of rows with UserID=1, there is just one group with 6 rows. That contiguous UserID requirements pretty much means you need to at least filter your dataset through a foreach loop before, since that requires look-behind... Does that requirement also apply to other "groups"? As in, if I have UserID=4 on rows 1, 3 and 4, with a 2 at row 2, do I discard everything, or make a group of three even if they are not contiguous? I haven't tested it, but only SKLTFZ's answer seems complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help. SKLTFZ's and TanvirArjel's answers were close but didn't achieve the expected results. I realized that you cannot achieve everything described above in Linq, so this is what I came up with and it achieves everything listed above:

PS: I renamed **var result1** to **ordered_photolist**

```
        List<Photos> ordered_photolist = photolist.OrderByDescending(p => p.PhotoLabel).ThenBy(r => r.UserID).ToList();

        List<Photos> temp_photolist = new List<Photos>();
        List<Photos> final_photolist = new List<Photos>();
        int UserID = -1;
        int UserIDCount = 0;

        foreach (Photos p in ordered_photolist)
        {
            if (UserID == -1)
            {
                UserID = p.UserID;
                temp_photolist.Add(p);
                UserIDCount++;
            }
            else
            {
                if ( UserID == p.UserID )
                {
                    temp_photolist.Add(p);
                    UserIDCount++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if ( UserIDCount >= 3 )
                    {
                        // add temp_photolist to final list
                        int index = final_photolist.FindIndex(item => item.UserID == UserID);
                        if (index == -1)
                        {
                            // element does not exists, do what you need
                            final_photolist.AddRange(temp_photolist);
                        }

                        temp_photolist.Clear();
                        temp_photolist.Add(p);
                        UserIDCount = 1;
                        UserID = p.UserID;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        temp_photolist.Clear();
                        UserIDCount = 0;
                        UserID = -1;
                    }
                }
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am not misunderstood the requirement, below function properly works (but it shouldn't the most efficient solution)

```
protected List<AnObject> aFunction(List<AnObject> sortedList)
{
    //Display groups of UserIDs and PhotoLabels where UserIDs appear 3 or more times in one group (eg: rows 4 and 5 where UserID = 88 and row 6 where UserID = 04 should be eliminated since the UserID = 88 appears just twice in the group and UserID = 04 appears only once in the group).
    //Display only the top most group of UserIDs and exclude any repeating UserIDs(eg: rows 7, 8 and 9 displays the UserID = 1 group.Don't display any other UserID=1 group such as rows 14,15 and 16.
    int pivot = -1;
    int cnt = 0;
    List<AnObject> masterList = new List<AnObject>();
    List<AnObject> subList = new List<AnObject>();
    //List<int> Excluded = new List<int>();
    foreach (AnObject r in sortedList)
    {
        if (pivot != r.UserID)
        {
            if (cnt > 2)
            {
                masterList.AddRange(subList);
                //Excluded.Add(pivot);
            }
            subList.Clear();
            pivot = -1;
            cnt = 0;
            //if (!Excluded.Contains(r.UserID))
            if (!masterList.Any(x => x.UserID == r.UserID))
            {
                pivot = r.UserID;
            }
        }
        subList.Add(r);
        cnt++;
    }
    return masterList;
}
```

To call it for testing

```
protected class AnObject
{
    public AnObject(int uid, string photolabel)
    {
        this.UserID = uid;
        this.PhotoLabel = photolabel;
    }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string PhotoLabel { get; set; }
}
protected void Execute()
{
    List<AnObject> sortedList = new List<AnObject>();
    sortedList.Add(new AnObject(92, "anystring"));
    sortedList.Add(new AnObject(92, "anystring"));
    sortedList.Add(new AnObject(92, "anystring"));
    sortedList.Add(new AnObject(88, "anystring"));
    sortedList.Add(new AnObject(88, "anystring"));
    sortedList.Add(new AnObject(4, "anystring"));
    sortedList.Add(new AnObject(1, "anystringfirst"));
    sortedList.Add(new AnObject(1, "anystringfirst"));
    sortedList.Add(new AnObject(1, "anystringfirst"));
    sortedList.Add(new AnObject(32, "anystring"));
    sortedList.Add(new AnObject(32, "anystring"));
    sortedList.Add(new AnObject(32, "anystring"));
    sortedList.Add(new AnObject(32, "anystring"));
    sortedList.Add(new AnObject(1, "anystringafter"));
    sortedList.Add(new AnObject(1, "anystringafter"));
    sortedList.Add(new AnObject(1, "anystringafter"));
    List<AnObject> bb = aFunction(sortedList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please wait! This is not the final answer! a little bit further modification is needed! modification is underway.

```
List<Photos> photolist = new List<Photos>()
        {
            new Photos() {UserID = 92, PhotoLabel = 20180729181046},
            new Photos() {UserID = 92, PhotoLabel = 20180729181041},
            new Photos() {UserID = 92, PhotoLabel = 20180729181037},
            new Photos() {UserID = 88, PhotoLabel = 20180729174415},
            new Photos() {UserID = 88, PhotoLabel = 20180729174405},
            new Photos() {UserID = 04, PhotoLabel = 20180729174358},
            new Photos() {UserID = 1, PhotoLabel = 20170924183847},
            new Photos() {UserID = 1, PhotoLabel = 20170921231422},
            new Photos() {UserID = 1, PhotoLabel = 20170920194624},
            new Photos() {UserID = 32, PhotoLabel = 20170820114728},
            new Photos() {UserID = 32, PhotoLabel = 20170820114725},
            new Photos() {UserID = 32, PhotoLabel = 20170820114421},
            new Photos() {UserID = 32, PhotoLabel = 20170820114416},
            new Photos() {UserID = 1, PhotoLabel = 20170225151023},
            new Photos() {UserID = 1, PhotoLabel = 20170225151000},
        };    

var photolist2 = photolist.GroupBy(g => g.UserID)
                .Select(p => new
                {
                    UserId = p.Key,
                    Count = p.Count()

                })
                .ToList();


var filteredPhotoList = photolist 
            .Join(photolist2, 
                photo => photo.UserID, 
                photo2 => photo2.UserId, 
                (photo, photo2) => new {UserId = photo.UserID, PhotoLabel = 
                photo.PhotoLabel, Count = photo2.Count})
            .Where(p => p.Count > 2).Select(p => new
            {
                p.UserId, p.PhotoLabel
            }).OrderByDescending(p => p.PhotoLabel).ThenBy(p => p.UserId).ToList();
```

Comment: did you fulfill the requirement Display only the top most group of UserIDs and exclude any repeating UserIDs (eg: rows 7,8 and 9 displays the UserID=1 group. Don't display any other UserID=1 group such as rows 14,15 and 16.

Comment: wait a minute please!

Comment: @SKLTFZ, thanks for noticing the complete requirement.

Comment: @sonnyk2016 I have updated my answer. Please check it. I have test it on my side. its working as expected!

Comment: it is not worked as expected, please check MO expected dataset

Comment: Yes! Got it ! I didn't notice the last requirement :)

Comment: @TanvirArjel the expected dataset outputs 10 items, your query returned 13 items, you need only output the first occurrence of dataset which met the requirement

Comment: @SKLTFZ yes! You are correct! a little bit strange requirements. Okay I see

Comment: @TanvirArjel  one more thing, your query also disordered the original sorted sequence, I'm not sure if it is expected too